# Boolean Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've been trying to simplify this equation:

> $Y = (¬AB + ¬C)(¬A + ¬D)$

.. into this equation.

> $Y  = ¬A¬C + ¬C¬D + ¬AB$

Unfortunately I keep going in circles with expanding and minimizing the booleans. Any tips or advice? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28not+A+and+B+or+not+C%29+and+%28not+A+or+not+D%29 won't show you the steps it took to get all its answers, but may come in handy at some point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following simplification:

$\neg AB(\neg A + \neg D) = \neg AB\neg A + \neg AB\neg D = \neg AB + \neg AB\neg D = \neg AB$.

Comment: Wow I realize I made a terrible mistake. I was cancelling ¬A¬AB because for some reason I thought ¬A¬A = 0 when in fact ¬A¬A = ¬A. Ugh.... thanks for the help!